# Javascript DOM Chrome Extension simple Script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I made an Extension for Firefox that random check all radio buttons & checkboxes on a website. Now I will make it for Chrome.

JS (`inject.js`):

```
function randomFromTo(from, to){
       return Math.floor(Math.random() * (to - from + 1) + from);
}

function autoFill () {
    for (i = 0; i < document.forms.length ;i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < document.forms[i].length ;j++) {
            if (document.forms[i].elements[j].type == "radio") {
                start = j;
                lastName = document.forms[i].elements[j].name;

                while (j < document.forms[i].length - 1 && lastName == document.forms[i].elements[j+1].name) {
                    j++;
                }
                rand = randomFromTo(start, j);
                document.forms[i].elements[rand].checked = true;
            }
            if (document.forms[i].elements[j].type == "checkbox") {
                start = j;
                lastName = document.forms[i].elements[j].name;

                while (j < document.forms[i].length - 1 && lastName == document.forms[i].elements[j+1].name) {
                    j++;
                }
                rand = randomFromTo(start, j);
                document.forms[i].elements[rand].checked = true;
            }
        }
    }
}

autoFill();
```

So I read a lot about `inject.js` and Content Scripts so I tried both. And made it like this.

```
{
  "name": "Auto Check Radio \u0026 Checkbox",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "",
  "homepage_url": "",
  "icons": {
    "16": "icons/icon16.png",
    "48": "icons/icon48.png",
    "128": "icons/icon128.png"
  },
  "default_locale": "en",
  "background": {
    "page": "src/bg/background.html",
    "persistent": true
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icons/icon16.png",
    "default_title": "Autocheck",
    "default_popup": "src/browser_action/browser_action.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "notifications",
    "http://*/",
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*"
  ],

  "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["https://*/*", "http://*/*"],
    "js": ["src/inject/inject.js"],
    "run_at": "document_end"
  }],
    "web_accessible_resources": ["src/inject/inject.js"],
      "js": ["src/inject/inject.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

But I've got no idea how I can run the code. On Firefox it is much easier.
I don't need any `background.html` or `browser_action.html`

I only want to run the script - in the current tab - by clicking the icon.

Chould anyone give me a tip where i place my script?

Answer (score 0):

Please read the [Overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview) document first. Especially the [Architecture](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch) part.

---

Any code that interacts with the page DOM must be in a [Content Script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts). You've already put the code in `src/inject.js`.

1. Now, you don't need any UI to pop up when you click the button, so **drop** the `"default_popup"` item from the manifest and its HTML.
2. You also don't want your code to randomly execute when a tab loads. That's what `"content_scripts"` section in the manifest is about, so simply **delete it**.
3. Finally, you don't need a background HTML file. They have been replaced by autogenerated pages that are built from a list of scripts. So:

   ```
     "background": {
       "scripts": ["src/bg/background.js"]
     },
     "browser_action": {
       "default_icon": "icons/icon16.png",
       "default_title": "Autocheck"
     },
   ```
4. Now, the only job of the background script is to register a handler for the button click. This is done through [`browserAction` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction):

   ```
   // src/bg/background.js
   chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
     chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: "src/inject/inject.js"});
   });
   ```

That's it, at this point it should work.

---

Now, to trim down the fat.

1. You don't need a persistent background page, since all it does is keeping simple event listeners that don't save any kind of state information. You can safely add [`"persistent": false`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages) to the manifest.
2. Your permissions are a massive overkill. There's a handy [`activeTab` permission](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab) that gives you access to the current page if your code is invoked by, say, browser action button press.

   In fact, that is the *only* permission your code needs. It will take care of `executeScript` call.

   ```
     "permissions" : ["activeTab"],
   ```

Comment: @ Xan - thanks a lot now it works fine incl. the autoscheck - now i can clean it up and build a package.